# Create a plugin with Calendar picker

Tags: plugins

I am currently creating a plugin and need one of the  fields to be a drop down calendar picker. Will I have to build this as well or is there a hook I can use to use something already produced by WordPress?

Comment: Hey @Max, does your question been answered ? If yes, please accept an answer ! 

Have a good day !

Answer (score 6):

jQuery Datepicker is included in WP Core, you can add it to your functions.php (for themes) or index.php (for plugins)

```
function styles_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    // Enqueue some theme-roller or default style...
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'styles_scripts', 11 );
```

Than in the HTML part where you need the datepicker

```
<input type="text" id="MyDate" name="MyDate" value=""/>
```

And finally in your Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});
```

> This code is not tested, I just typed it here and hope it work well, let me know if you need more information or correction.

Comment: I think that your answer should be an edition of the @WilltheWebMechanic answer that was made before yours.

Comment: This answer predates the other by 4 minutes, @cybmeta.

Comment: Oooops, yes, sorry, I don't know why I made the reverse reading. I feel quite silly ;)

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery UI datepicker is included in WordPress. While not really a 'dropdown' calendar picker, it should meet your needs and can be easily configured to reflect localizations of wherever it is running.

enqueue it with `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );` or add it as a dependency as needed to js that your plugin is loading. You'll need to ensure that there is some css available for it as well.

Comment: You should add some example code.